# Finding the Paramertric Coordinates of the Maximum and Minimum points of a Certain Curve

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, parametric, maxima-minima

I was studying for some quizzes when a wild question appears. It goes like this:

> Find the paramertric coordinates of the maximum and minimum points of 
>   the following curves. The curve is $x = 3 \cos \theta$ ;$\space$ $ y = 4 \sin \theta$

My work:

I need to get the rectangular equation described by the parametric equation.
I remember the relation $(\sin \theta)^2 + (\cos \theta)^2 = 1$

Getting the $\cos \theta:$ $\cos \theta = \frac{x}{3}$
Getting the $\sin \theta:$ $\sin \theta = \frac{y}{4}$

Substituting the newly-found variables to $(\sin \theta)^2 + (\cos \theta)^2 = 1$,
it becomes $$\left( \frac{x}{3} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{y}{4} \right)^2 = 1$$

By using the implicit differentiation, we got:
$$\left( \frac{x}{3} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{y}{4} \right)^2 = 1$$ 
$$\left( \frac{1}{9} \right)\left( 2x \right) + \left( \frac{1}{16} \right)\left( 2 y y' \right) = 0 $$
$$\left( \frac{2}{9} \right)\left( 2x \right) + \left( \frac{1}{8} \right)\left(y y' \right) = 0$$
$$\left( \frac{1}{8} \right)\left(y y' \right) = \left( \frac{-2}{9} \right)\left( 2x \right) $$
$$y' = \frac{-16x}{9y}$$

We got to make the derivative expressed as a single variable, so we need to get the $y$ in terms of $x$ in the equation 
$\left( \frac{x}{3} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{y}{4} \right)^2 = 1.$

getting the $y$ from $\left( \frac{x}{3} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{y}{4} \right)^2 = 1,$ it is:
$$y = \frac{4}{3}\left((9 - x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$$

Then ,substituting it to the equation $y' = \frac{-16x}{9y},$ it becomes:
$$y' = \frac{-16x}{9\left( \frac{4}{3}\left((9 - x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) \right)}$$
$$ y' = \frac{-4}{3}\left((9 - x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$$

To get the minimum and maximum points of the rectangular equation, we set $\frac{dy}{dx} = y'$ to zero.
$$ y' = \frac{-4}{3}\left((9 - x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$$
$$ 0 = \frac{-4}{3}\left((9 - x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$$
$$ 0 = (9 - x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$ 0 = (9 - x^2)$$
$$x^2 = 9$$

We get $x = \pm 3$

To determine whether $x = -3$ is a minimum or maximum point, we use the first derivative test.
Letting $x = -3$ as the critical/base point, we let $x = -99$ and $x = +99.$ If $x = -99$ is plugged into 
the equation $ y' = \frac{-4}{3}\left((9 - x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right),$ the value of $y$ is imaginary. 
If $x = +99$ is plugged into 
the equation $ y' = \frac{-4}{3}\left((9 - x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right),$ the value of $y$ is imaginary too.

To determine whether $x =  +3$ is a minimum or maximum point, we use the first derivative test.
Letting $x = -3$ as the critical/base point, we let $x = -99$ and $x = +99.$ If $x = -99$ is plugged into 
the equation $ y' = \frac{-4}{3}\left((9 - x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right),$ the value of $y$ is imaginary. 
If $x = +99$ is plugged into 
the equation $ y' = \frac{-4}{3}\left((9 - x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right),$ the value of $y$ is imaginary too.

At this point, I'm stuck, because I can't determine if $x = \pm 3$ is a minimum or maximum point. I used large numbers
 just to make sure I see the change of signs as I pass through the derivative (+, 0, -) or (-, 0, +)

How do you get the minimum and maximum points of the curve shown above?

Comment: If the problem is asking for the *parametric* coordinates, why convert to a Cartesian equation? Seems to me that you can find the max/min values of $y$ directly from the parameterization.

Comment: @amd How to find the max/min values of $y$ directly from the parameterization? Seems the idea is new to me though.....

Comment: It’s no surprise that setting $x$ to $\pm99$ is getting you nowhere since those are values that $x$ can never have: $-3\le3\cos\theta\le3$ for all $\theta$.

Comment: You could differentiate $4\sin\theta$ with respect to $\theta$, find where this is zero, and so on, or simply realize that $-1\le\sin\theta\le1$, so $-4\le y\le4$, with equality when $\sin\theta=\pm1$. However, I should also ask what is meant by “maximum and minimum points” in this problem, since that’s not entirely clear from context.

Comment: Did you recognize that you have an ellipse centered at the origin?

Comment: Max/min at $y=\pm 4, \theta = \pi/2$

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a comment: since no interval is given for $\theta$, the convention then is to choose the maximal one, meaning $[0, 2\pi)$. Notice that this a *closed* curve (i.e. it gets back at its starting point), and as such it makes no rigorous sense to speak about its extrema. On the other hand, I believe that the problem is informally asking you about the vertices of the curve, which I am going to find next.

Almost surely the problem does *not* expect you to use differential calculus to solve it, because the computations can get a bit ugly (and time-consuming during an exam).

You have correctly noticed that the given curve can be presented in Cartesian coordinates as

$$\frac {x^2} 9 + \frac {y^2} {16} = 1$$

which I guess that you are *supposed to recognize* as an ellipse centered in $(0,0)$ and having the coordinate axes as its own axes of symmetry. You are next *supposed* to know how to *sketch* such an ellipse, from which it becomes apparent that the vertices are $(\pm 3, 0)$ and $(0, \pm 4)$.

Finally, you are required to find the parametric coordinates of thse points. Keep in mind that when $\theta = 0$ you are on the $x$ axis to the right, when $\theta = \frac \pi 2$ you are upward on the $y$ axis, when $\theta = \pi$ you are on the $x$ axis to the left, and when $\theta = \frac {3\pi} 2$ you are downward on the $y$ axis. This means that $(3,0) = (3 \cos 0, \sin 0)$, $(0, 4) = (\cos \frac \pi 2, 4 \sin \frac \pi 2)$, $(-3,0) = (3 \cos \pi, \sin \pi)$ and $(0, -4) = (\cos \frac {3\pi} 2, 4 \sin \frac {3\pi} 2)$.

Answer (score 0):

The max/min values occur at the values of $\theta$ for which

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy/d\theta}{dx/d\theta}=0 $$

which occurs when

$$ \frac{dy}{d\theta}=4\cos\theta=0 $$

So the solution is

$$\theta=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$$

(or, more generally)

$$\theta=2\pi n\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$$

But $\theta=\pm\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ will be sufficient to find the max/min.

\begin{eqnarray}
\left(3\cos\frac{\pi}{2},4\sin\frac{\pi}{2}\right)&=&(0,4)\text{ max}\\
\left(3\cos\frac{-\pi}{2},4\sin\frac{-\pi}{2}\right)&=&(0,-4)\text{ min}
\end{eqnarray}